# Is there way to get waterfall Active Dialog for particular user from another controller in same solution where no Dialog context exist

Tags: c#, botframework

I have one virtual Assistant bot where I am using WaterFall dialog.I have one more controller there in same solution called notification controller. I want to send notification after checking Active dialog of current user. Is there way to get Active Dialog of particular user in Notifiation controller where as Notification Controller is having only turn Context no DialogContext.

below one is one of notification controller's method

```
    private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, 
      CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Here i have turncontext but i need dialogcontext to check active dialog for the user before i send notification to him through Virtual Assistant bot.

Comment: can you add some code snippets or research you have done? please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Manish please have a look on it now.